# How to pass data into collision handler?

Tags: python, collision, pymunk

Using the .separate Collision handler function in pymunk, how would you pass in an array to be updated and returned? I currently have a global array called particles which seems to be giving a "set change in size iteration" error as I'm updating it in the collision handler.

```
def remove_particle1(self, arbiter, space, data): 
        particle1_shape = arbiter.shapes[0] 
        particle2_shape = arbiter.shapes[1]
        if temperature> 50:
            for particle_to_remove in [particle for particle in particles if particle.body == particle1_shape.body]:
                particles.remove(particle_to_remove) 
            
            for particle_to_remove in [particle for particle in particles if particle.body == particle2_shape.body]:
               
                particles.remove(particle_to_remove)
        
            space.remove(particle1_shape, particle1_shape.body)
```

Comment: Does it help if you make a temp array of items to be removed, and the iterate through that one?

Answer (score 0):

Use `lambda`, and pass in your array.

In this example I'm passing in `special_ball` instead of an array. I hope this conveys the idea?

```
# Just a class from my code
special_ball = Ball() 

# NOTE the inline {...} dictionary, in place of data
handler.separate = lambda arbiter, space, data: remove_particle1(arbiter, space, {
    "special_ball": special_ball
})
```

Gleaned from [Pymunk make box slowly push up from one of its corners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75368685/pymunk-make-box-slowly-push-up-from-one-of-its-corners)